# How do I apply a separate AssemblyInfo version per project using Rake/Albacore?

Tags: .net, ruby, rake, versioning, albacore

I have a solution with multiple projects in it. One request is to have different versions for each project. I thought I had a solution, but not knowing much about ruby I'm not sure how to fix it or why it is happening. Here are the pertinent parts of my rakefile:

```
projects = ["ProjectOne", "ProjectTwo"]

assemblyinfo :assemblyinfo do |asm|
   projects.each do | proj |
      bumper_file proj + "/VERSION"
      asm.version = bumper_version.to_s
      asm.file_version = bumper_version.to_s

      asm.product_name = proj
      asm.output_file = proj + "/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs"
   end
end
```

Everything builds fine, but each project gets the version of the first project in the list. Interestingly, if I change it slightly to this:

```
projects.each do | proj |
   bumper_file proj + "/VERSION"
   assemblyinfo :assemblyinfo do |asm|
      asm.version = bumper_version.to_s
      asm.file_version = bumper_version.to_s

      asm.product_name = proj
      asm.output_file = proj + "/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs"
   end
end
```

Each project then gets the version of the last file in the list. How do I set the version to what is found in the VERSION file in each project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I read your question correctly, you have two projects each with a separate `VERSION` file in some project-specific sub-folder. Something like this...

```
my-project/
  source/
    projectA/
      Properties/
        AssemblyInfo.cs
      VERSION
    projectB/
      Properties/
        AssemblyInfo.cs
      VERSION
```

And you want to a Rake/Albacore task that will apply the correct version to each project. The way you have your first task structured, you're only creating one task and you're overwriting the properties assigned to it with that loop!

```
assemblyinfo :assemblyinfo do |asm|  #=> one :version task
  projects.each do |proj|            #=> many iterations
    # ... assignment ...             #=> overwriting properties
  end
end
```

The second task definition, the "slight tweak", is actually kind-of accidentally working. You're defining the entire task each time through the projects loop, but with the same name. This is where you're hitting a little-known Rake feature that you might not have been aware of... tasks with the same name are appended to one another. So, you're actually making 2 tasks with 1 name with different bodies.

```
projects.each do |proj|                #=> many iterations
  assemblyinfo :assemblyinfo do |asm|  #=> many tasks mapped to the same name
    # ... assignment ...               #=> separate properties
  end
end
```

To make things more clear, I recommend a task definition where every `assemblyinfo` task gets it's own unique name, then you construct a `version` task that's dependent on all of them.

```
projects.each do |proj|
  name = File.join(proj, "Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs")
  bumper_file = File.join(proj, "VERSION")

  assemblyinfo name do |asm|
    asm.output_file = asm
    asm.version = asm.file_version = bumper_version.to_s
    asm.product_name = proj
  end
end

desc "Version every project in the solution"
task :version => projects.map { |proj| File.join(proj, "Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs") }
```

Comment: I understand how rake tasks work a lot better now, unfortunately this still doesn't quite work. It looks to me like it should, and my guess would be that it is some kind of behavior from how [version_bumper](https://github.com/jondot/version_bumper) works. I can update other fields in the AssemblyInfo.cs file specific to the project(i.e. the product name), just not the version string, which is the only thing coming from version_bumper.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know how `version_bumper` works. Just consider giving all Rake tasks a unique name (I usually do a lot of this creating/naming in a loop).

Comment: Marking as the answer since this got me most of the way there and everything else appears to be working as intended.